# How to display only the word "Running" in a Get-Service cmdlet

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a script in Powershell that inserts data into a SQL table but I am having trouble figuring out how to return the status of the service as only the word "Running".

Right now it is returning `@{Status=Running}` under the status column of my database table and I just want it to return the word "Running". How do I go about this?

```
foreach($status in $serviceStatus)
    {
        if ($status.status -eq "Running") 
        {  
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName]([ServerName], [ServiceName], [Status], [Date])
            VALUES  ('$serverName', '$service', '$status', '$Date')
            GO"

            Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'ServerName' -Database 'DatabaseName' -query $SQL 

            Write-Host "***Running: $($serverName)***"                       

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try changing your value to `'$status.status'` instead of `'$status'` in the `insert` statement.  That looks like json or something else...

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. All it does is return it as `@{Status=Running}.status` @sgeddes

Comment: `'$($status.status)'`

Comment: oh wow. That simple, huh? You got it @EBGreen. You da man!

Comment: @EBGreen please write a solution and derekg8881 accept this solution.

Comment: I don't want to and you can't make me. I come to stackoverflow and check questions when I am waiting for scripts to run. I rarely have time to type out a proper answer with explanations and good details. Instead if there is something quick that I can type to get the OP going then I will. If you feel like typing that up as a good quality answer then help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you install dbatools, you could do that in one line:

```
Instal-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser # only once

Get-Service | Where-Object Status -eq 'Running'| Select @{n='Server';e={if($_.MachineName -eq '.'){$env:COMPUTERNAME}else{$_.MachineName}}}, Name, Status,@{n='Date'; e={Get-Date}} | Write-DbaDataTable -SqlInstance $sql -Database TEMPDB -Table abc -AutoCreateTable
```